Find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(n\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)\left(e^x-1-\frac{x}{1!}-\frac{x^2}{2!}-\cdots-\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)\right)$

Find the value of $A$ where
$$A=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(n\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)\left(e^x-1-\frac{x}{1!}-\frac{x^2}{2!}-\cdots-\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)\right)$$

By using the expansion of $e^x$, I have simplified the expression into
$$A=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(n\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)\left(\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{x^i}{i!}\right)\right)$$
After this I am having a hard time in exploring further into this problem.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

All the even terms are $0$.

@JulioPuerta yes I noticed that...but how can I make use of this information

You can use the integral representation, or maybe it can be derived, of the Lerch transcendent for the inner sum. Summing over $n$ uses a geometric type series and integrating the result gives $A=\frac12\left(\frac{(x-1)x}{x^2+1}+\tan^{-1}(x)\right)$ which seems to match here

@ТymaGaidash never heard of Lerch function...i prefer an elementary solution...but any kind of solution is accepted

Correction: the previous result in a previous comment is for $\sum\limits_{j=n+1}^\infty\frac{x^j}j$

Some thoughts. (We need to prove that the function is differentiable etc.)
We have
$$A'(x) = A(x) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(n\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)\cdot \frac{x^n}{n!}\right)
= A(x) + x\cos x.$$
Solve the ODE to obtain
$$A(x) = - \frac12 x\cos x + \frac12 \sin x + \frac12 x\sin x + c\mathrm{e}^x.$$
Since $A(0) = 0$, we have $c = 0$. Thus,
$$A(x) = - \frac12 x\cos x + \frac12 \sin x + \frac12 x\sin x.$$

First of all, for all fixed $x$, $\sum_{i \geqslant n + 1} \left|\frac{x^i}{i!}\right| = \mathrm{O}\left(\frac{1}{n!}\right)$ by Taylor inequality hence the sum is absolutely convergent. Then, notice that $\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right) = 1$ if $n \equiv 1 \ [4]$, $-1$ if $n \equiv 3\ [4]$, $0$ if $n \equiv 0\ [2]$ so the sum simplifies as,
$$
A = \sum_{k \geqslant 0} (-1)^k(2k + 1)\sum_{i \geqslant 2k + 2} \frac{x^i}{i!} = \sum_{i \geqslant 2} \frac{x^i}{i!}\sum_{k = 0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{i - 2}{2} \right\rfloor} (-1)^k(2k + 1).
$$
We can exchange the sums by absolute convergence. Then, I let you check by induction that for all integer $j$,
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{j - 1} (-1)^k(2k + 1) = -(-1)^jj.
$$
Therefore,
$$
A = -\sum_{i \geqslant 2} \frac{x^i}{i!}(-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \right\rfloor}\left\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \right\rfloor = A_{\mathrm{even}} + A_{\mathrm{odd}},
$$
where $A_{\mathrm{even}}$ (resp. $A_{\mathrm{odd}}$) are computing by summing on all the $i \geqslant 2$ even (resp. odd). We have,
\begin{align*}
A_{\mathrm{even}} & = -\sum_{i \geqslant 2|i \textrm{ even}} \frac{x^i}{i!}(-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \right\rfloor}\left\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \right\rfloor\\
& = -\sum_{j \geqslant 0} \frac{x^{2j + 2}}{(2j + 2)!}(-1)^{j + 1}(j + 1)\\
& = \frac{x}{2}\sum_{j \geqslant 0} (-1)^j\frac{x^{2j + 1}}{(2j + 1)!}\\
& = \frac{x}{2}\sin(x).
\end{align*}
I let you compute $A_{\mathrm{odd}}$, it is the same idea. You have to make appear the series of $\sin$ and $\cos$. You should also verify my computations, it is easy to make mistakes with this kind of calculus.

Another way to solve the problem is to use:

How to integrate $ \int x^n e^x dx$?

or the regularized gamma function to find:
$$\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty\frac{x^j}{j!}=\frac{e^x}{n!}\int_0^x e^{-t}t^ndt$$
This gives:
$$A(x)=\int_0^xe^{x-t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{t^n}{(n-1)!}\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}2\right)dt$$
The inner sum can be interpreted as  $e^x$’s Maclaurin series if writing $\sin(\frac{\pi n}2)$ in complex form, so we are left with:
$$A(x)=\int_0^xe^{x-t} t\cos(t) dt=\frac12x\sin(x)-\frac12x\cos(x)+\frac12\sin(x)$$
